# Mapping word tags/labels to their index

Tags: python, regex, pandas, numpy, nlp

Here is a sample word/tag sentence pair sampled from a dataframe in NER

```
B-per   Mr
B-per   .
I-per   Trump
O        ’
O        s
O       tweets
O       began
O       just
O       moments
O       after
O       a
B-org   Fox
I-org   News
O       report
O       by
B-per   Mike
I-per   Tobin
0       who 
0       never
0       arrived

this for example has index of 1 to 61, by manually counting down the columns from B-per to I-per
```

now, I want to locate the start and end span for different sentences across a dataframe, which in this case is the first B-per to the last I-per.

Thus I feel like i might break it down into a series of steps

1. locate the first person tag B-per
2. locate the last I-per
3. index the sentence and find the index of the first letter of the word B-per
4. find the index of the last letter of the word I-per.

How do i accomplish this?

Comment: Could you please explain how the span of a sentence is selected as B-per to last I-per. The reason for this question is that one starts with sentence boundaries and then parses them through an NER algorithm.

Comment: i chose B-per and I-per because in the example, they convey my idea. is there an algorithm to generate the spans if i pass the start and end tag as arguments?

Comment: Generally speaking, one has sentences to begin with. Then, those sentences are put through the NER algorithm. So one always knows the sentence start and end. Do you have sentences to begin with?

Comment: yes, The sentences in this case tagged using BERT transformers, but I still have to extract the indexes of select tags